# Why is this question being repeatedly closed?

Tags: support

I'm trying to ask a very specific question about a very specific aircraft in [this question](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/83812/why-does-boeing-247d-have-reverse-slope-windows-when-they-were-removed-from-the?noredirect=1#comment223062_83812).

It keeps being closed as a dup, but it is absolutely not a dup. The question they are saying answers it, **which I asked** in the first place, states that all 247D aircraft had slope-forward windows.

This aircraft is a 247D with slope-back windows.

That original answer comes from a wiki article on the 247, which is precisely why I'm asking, because the statement is obviously wrong (as one can literally see in the images) and I'm trying to find out a real answer. But I can't, because people keep saying its a dup!

Can someone please reopen this? Or offer a suggestion on how to go about not being snowball-closed every time?

Comment: For future cases: If you ask a question, which is similar or based on another question, I would always link that one in your new question and explain how/why the questions differ. This shows that you know about the other question and makes it easier for reviewers to see the difference.

Answer (score 6):

I lean towards agreeing with you, so I have cast the deciding reopen vote. You may find it gets closed again, at which point I think we can safely say the community has spoken.

Comment: Thank you, it immediately received a useful answer.